# Помогите мне с system();

Tags: c++

В общем я делаю оболочку для одной программы. Для запуска этой программы нужно в cmd отправить вот такой запрос: "C:\folder\executable.exe" xxx.exe "C:\folder\dynamiclinklibrary.dll" Это всё обязательно в одну строку. Я условно делю на 3 части: "C:\folder\executable.exe" - сама программа xxx.exe - процесс "C:\folder\dynamiclinklibrary.dll" - библиотека Я новичок и никогда не работал с system. В общем это нужно мне засунут в system. Если это сделать вставить также как в cmd будет ошибка во 2 части. Помогите прошу уже 2 день мучаюсь.

Comment: Проблема в чем конкретно? Покажите, *как* вы это делаете...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LBlyLFE.png проблема на лицо. как сделать эту команду в C++

Comment: `"\"C:\\folder\\executable.exe\" xxx.exe \"C:\\folder\\dynamiclinklibrary.dll\""`

Comment: Или `R"("C:\folder\executable.exe" xxx.exe "C:\folder\dynamiclinklibrary.dll")"`.

Answer (score 0):

Либо так:

```
R"("C:\folder\executable.exe" xxx.exe "C:\folder\dynamiclinklibrary.dll")"
```

Либо так:

```
"\"C:\\folder\\executable.exe\" xxx.exe \"C:\\folder\\dynamiclinklibrary.dll\""
```

[Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672257/how-to-properly-use-system-to-execute-a-command-in-c)